# Associations in Ruby on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I've got a question to associations in rails.
I am trying to create a comment for a post which has a subject.
So my routs file looks like this:

```
resources :subjects do
  resources :post do
    resources :comments
  end
end
```

Now am I trying to create a form in the show.html.erb file of the post so someone can create a comment. 
I've tried it this way which I found in the rails guide:

'posts/show.html.erb'

```
<%= form_for {[@post, @post.comments.build]} do |f| %>
//fill in form
<% end %>
```

'posts.controller.rb'

```
def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end
```

But this gives me an error. If you need any other codeparts, feel free to ask.

Error Message

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `post_comments_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f9a4429d5e8>:0x007f9a42c01fc8>):
 8:   <strong>Text:</strong>
 9:   <%= @post.text %>
10: </p>
11: <%= form_for ([@post, @post.comments.build]) do |f| %>
12:     <p>
13:       <%= f.label :text %><br>
14:       <%= f.text_area :text %>
```

Comment: Can you share your console log with error ?

Comment: Added it to my question

Comment: On which line you getting this error ?

Comment: Line 11,
I will update the error message -> html tags have been applied to the message

Comment: try to build your  post.build_comment in your controller show action in different variable and add url option to your form_for and give the path of the method on which your form will go on submit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those paths are grouped under `resources :subjects`, so your path will be `subjects_post_comments_path`, or if you prefer to use polymorphic paths it will be `[@subjects, @post, @post.comments.build]`.

You can run `rake routes | grep comments` to see the paths for all of your comments routes.

Comment: `resources :post` should also be `resources :posts` or `resource :post`.

Comment: Possibly useful suggestion: you can always do `rake routes` to see a list of the available routes. They also show the paths that are available. In that list, the first bit of text (if present) will show you the path. Generally if you add `_path` to the end you'll find the relevant path as described in Jarred's answer above.